# What is the method to change the aspectRatio of JCrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop, aspect-ratio, jcrop

How do I change the aspectRatio of the JCrop on the fly?

Sorry for the simple question but the all the manual, the documentation and the discussions are on http://deepliquid.com which is dead from yesterday, and I really need to finish something in this evening.

If someone has by any chance the JCrop manual saved could you please upload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(A little late for @user1236048, but it may be helpful for others.)

The aspect ratio can be changed using the jCrop API using the `setOptions` method:

```
jcrop_api.setOptions(
{
    aspectRatio: 2/1
});
```